# Scaling Child GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of cubes instantiated in a Parent Game Object. So , i have written a function to auto scale the Parent in order to group scale the children. I use the function because based on different inputs the number of spawned cubes changes. The function works well the 1st time. If i destroy the children and re spawn them based on the new input my auto-scale function doesn't work. The cubes spawn too small. What am i missing ?

This is the script :

```
    private void ScaleMaze(GameObject GO)
    {

        //Debug.Log("On Scale Function : " + Heigth + " "+ Width);
        max = Math.Max(Heigth, Width);

        if (max <= 5)
        {
            Scale_Factor = 5;
        }else
        {
            Scale_Factor = (float)50 / (float)max;
        }

        GO.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Scale_Factor , 0.5f,Scale_Factor);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are forgetting to reset the parent after destroying all the children.

Comment: Or you can use localScale on child objects, and when u add a new child apply the parent scale locally

Comment: @akaBase Worked for me !  I noticed that i reseted Parent's localscale in the wrong function , thats why it didnt work. Thank you !

Comment: @Menyus Upvote.

Comment: Also a minor code quality improvement would be to change this literal: `(float)50` to `50f`